# Get and display all values from database row separately based on select (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i'm stuck making an invoicing application. I want to have an option where you can add an existing customer from the `customers` table and add those values to the invoice.

The values i want to display are `company_name`, `vat_number` and `iban_number`.

I tried doing this:

```
<%= select_tag 'choose customer', options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.customers.all, 'id', 'company_name') %>
```

But obviously this only gets the value of `company_name`.

I tried using `collection.select` but that one also gets only one value of the database row instead of all 3.

---

**I want to be able to select from a list or table row containing just the `company_name` but when i click on that company_name it has to also display `vat_number` and `iban_number`(separately, on different parts of the page).**

*something like this in my invoice/_form would be optimal:*

```
<p><%= customer.selected(:company_name) %></p>
<p><%= customer.selected(:vat_number) %></p>
<p><%= customer.selected(:iban_number) %></p>
```

**This is my invoices controller:**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices =  current_user.invoices.all
    flash.now[:notice] = "U haven't added any invoices yet" if @invoices.empty?
  end

  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.new
    @invoice.build_company
    @invoice.products.build
    @invoice.build_customer
  end

  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Your invoice is saved.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { @invoice.build_company
                      @invoice.products.build
                      @invoice.build_customer
                      render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Your invoice is edited.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Your invoice is deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = current_user.invoices.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal, :subtotal, :total, :footer,
                                      customer_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :address_line_1, :iban_number, :vat_number, :zip_code, :_destroy],
                                      company_attributes: [:id, :iban_number, :company_name, :_destroy],
                                      products_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :description, :unitprice, :btw, :total])
    end
end
```

The select dropdown is inside of the new action and the selected data should be visible in the new action, index action and show action and editable in the edit action.

---

I read the entire ruby docs and they are very vague about this particular instance.

**Note:** *i don't want just an answer, i want to be able to understand how to do it in future projects with different criteria. And i want other people to understand the underlying concepts aswell.*

Any ideas on how to achieve this or where to look for the answer would be **much much** appreciated

Comment: vat_number and iban_number are specific to company?

Comment: They belong to customer, i had accidentally switched customers with companies in the options_from_collection_for_select. Edited it.

Comment: how about get those values as an array at controller and use them in view ?

Comment: But how do you combine that with a select option where you can choose from one data attribute and display all 3 of the data attributes separately on different parts of the page and in all the controller action views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag 'choose customer', options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.customers.all, 'id', 'company_name'), id: "choose_customer" %>
```

You can bind the change event from the rails to an ajax call, send the `id` of the selected object, if you want to fetch the data based on the selected value, `call a method`, then handle the view using that response

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#choose_company").bind("change",function() { 
        if ($(this).val() != undefined) { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url : "/my_action", 
                data: {'company': $(this).val()}, 
                dataType: "json", 
                type: "GET", 
                success : function(data) { 
                    $(".display_btw").html(data["btw_number"]); 
                    $(".display_iban").html(data["iban_number"]); 
                    $('.chosen_company_btw').val(data["btw_number"]).text(data["btw_number"]); 
                    $('.chosen_company_iban').val(data["iban_number"]).text(data["iban_number"]); 
                } 
            }) 
        } 
    }) 
})
```

Your controller action can be something like,

`get '/my_action', to: 'invoices#my_action'` add this route.

```
def my_action 
    if params[:company].present? 
        @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:company]) 
        @data = Hash.new 
        @data["btw_number"] = @company.btw_number 
        @data["iban_number"] = @company.iban_number 
        render json: @data and return false 
    end 
end
```

This action returns the `vat_number` and `iban_number` which should be displayed in the view depending in the selected value.

Comment: @luissimo, please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping but note that the select dropdown is inside of my invoices new view and the selected data should be visible in the edit, index and show action aswell. I edited my OP with the invoices controller.

Comment: "selected data should be visible in the edit, index and show action aswell",  means? pls elaborate.

Comment: hmm okay but i get this error 'Couldn't find Customer without an ID' from '@customer = current_user.customers.find(params[:id])'   , same error with your exact code.

Comment: I have given `(params[:customer])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126006/discussion-between-sravan-and-luissimo).

Answer (score 0):

Create a method on the `customers` model that concatenates this information together in a friendly, human-readable way:

```
def friendly_info
  "#{company_name} (#{vat_number}) - IBAN #{iban_number}"
end
```

Then use that method in your select statement in place of `company_name`.

Comment: And how do you call "#{company_name} (#{vat_number}) - IBAN #{iban_number}" in a view? separately. Like company _name has to come somewhere at the top of the page and the other 2 at the bottom for instance.

Comment: Then call them separately.  You haven't destroyed or altered those attributes, you've just made a 'convenience' method for showing them.  You could create any number of those methods without changing the underlying data.

Comment: OK, I just saw your edits.  You want the select box to only have the company name, but then after selecting the customer, you want to show the other information elsewhere on the page.  That's a more complicated problem - you'll have to use javascript for that.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what i want.. and i understand that Javascript is necessary but i need to split the attributes somehow first in order to be able to effectively use Javascript(jquery).