# Get and display all values from database based on option select (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Hello i need help on my Kitchen inventory website on Ruby on rails. I am facing the issue is.
I have a table name  `Ingredient` and its attributes are `Name, Image, Description`. When i save data in my `Ingredient` table then i want to display the saved data on my **index view**, AS LIKE when i select option from the option select. Then data will show.

> In Simple words on my **Index view** when i select option "APPLE" from
>   option select menu then the data is related to "APPLE" display on my
>   **index view**. Other wise it does not display.

This is my **Index View**

```html
<%= select_tag 'choose ingredient', options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.ingredients.all, 'user_id', 'Name'), id: "choose ingredient" %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= ingredient.Name %></td>
      <td><%= ingredient.Quantity %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', ingredient %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ingredient_path(ingredient) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ingredient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my **controller**

```html
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ingredient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /ingredients
  # GET /ingredients.json
  def index
    @ingredients = Ingredient.where(user_id: current_user)
  end

  # GET /ingredients/1
  # GET /ingredients/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ingredients/new
  def new
    @ingredient = current_user.ingredients.build
  end

  # GET /ingredients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ingredients
  # POST /ingredients.json
  def create
    @ingredient = current_user.ingredients.build(ingredient_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ingredient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ingredient, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ingredient }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ingredients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ingredients/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ingredient.update(ingredient_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ingredient, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ingredient }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ingredients/1
  # DELETE /ingredients/1.json
  def destroy
    @ingredient.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ingredients_url, notice: 'Ingredient was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ingredient
      @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ingredient_params
      params.require(:ingredient).permit(:Name, :Quantity)
    end
end
```

[I try to find the solution on stack overflow but i don't know how i use this for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061008/get-and-display-all-values-from-database-row-separately-based-on-select-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

Heres an example:

After installing the gem in your index controller set it like this:

```
def index
  ingredients = Ingredient.where(user_id: current_user)
  @q = ingredients.ransack(params[:q])
  @ingredients = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

Now in your view you can set up a search field or dropdown which will filter as required:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  # Search if the name field contains...
  <%= f.label :Name_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :Name_cont %>


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You will need to modify this depending on the fields in your database